# Places (Search) API according to a bounding box fails in some countries

Tags: here-api

I am querying Here Maps Places Search API to get places according to a category (eg. hospital) within an interest area delimited by a bounding box (giving an explicit location context). This is how I construct a request:

```
var url = "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?size=500&in=" + boundingBox + "&q=" + placeCategory + "&app_id=" + id + "&app_code=" + code;
```

I get expected results for many places around the world but not for London, England and Malmo, Sweden. In those two places, I get places that are outside of the bounding box but share the same latitude. It's a line of points around the globe. What might be going on?

Comment: Could you share a query with an actual bounding box and place category for which you get results outside of the bounding box?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reaction.  I give examples of two categories but it shows places outside of the bounding box no matter the category, only depending on geographic location:  places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?size=500&in=0.0105005,51.4625292,-0.000929,51.4666245&q=hospitals& + credentials and places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?size=500&in=13.1570448,55.4942764,12.8932697,55.6366115&q=schools& + credentials

Answer (score 0):

We have checked and the specified bounding boxes are not valid bounding boxes. So the API returns results using the location context included in the request header.
See documentation:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/location-contexts.html